# Files keep opening in new window instead of tabs

Tags: textmate

I've been looking around on Google and here but I can't seem to figure out how to prevent textmate to open files in new windows instead of opening in new tabs.

This is a feature I'm positive is possible because I've seen it in railscasts videos before :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the helpfile:

> In the current version of TextMate (1.5) file tabs are only supported when a project is created. Fortunately it is easy to create a project, namely by selecting File → New Project (⌃⌘N).

IOW, you have to create a new Project and then you can create tab-based files inside that by using Shift-⌘N